# Script not working with cloudflare ssl on blogger, but works when https is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, https, blogger

This script is not working with https on Bloggger custom domain Cloudflare free ssl.. It can work when https is off, but its not working with https.

It is the script for showing a post description on home page.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.post-summary').each(function() {
    var summary = $(this),
      getURL = summary.attr('data-url');
    $.get(getURL, function(data) {
        var text = $(data).find('.post-body').text().substr(0, 250);
        summary.html('<p>' + text + '...</p>');
      }, "html");
  });
});
```

HTML for the above script:

```
<div class='resumo'>
  <span class='post-summary' expr:data-url='data:post.url'/>
</div>
<div style='clear: both;'/>
  <a class='read-more anchor-hover' expr:href='data:post.url'>Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the data tag - `data:post.url`. This returns the HTTP version of the post URL (which gets blocked by browsers when the request is made via the jQuery code). To make sure that `data:post.url` tag always returns the HTTPS version of the post URL, append `.https` at the end this tag. The HTML code will change as follows -

```
<div class='resumo'>
  <span class='post-summary' expr:data-url='data:post.url.https'/>
</div>
<div style='clear: both;'/>
  <a class='read-more anchor-hover' expr:href='data:post.url.https'>Read More</a>
</div>
```